# ASP.NET not passing credentials to SQL Server when using chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, kerberos

My company is planning to upgrade all our users to windows 7, and with it upgrading all the user browsers to chrome.

We have several intranet sites using asp.net mvc and mvc webapi. I have set my intranet to the trusted domain setting, and I can confirm that when viewing a page in chrome the `User.Identity.Name` property is correctly set to my information. 
However, when I try to do any action that requires sql server connectivity it fails instantly, complaining about Anonymous login which is disabled.

This is problematic, as we would like to get our users off IE.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link I misread your question. Looks like the problem you're having is that Chrome isn't delegating Kerberos credentials... https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/lIw5ojBDER4 "The trick is Chrome must be started with the --auth-server-whitelist parameter. For example:  `google-chrome --auth-server-whitelist="*gurulabs.com"` "

Comment: Yes they are using windows credentials and we are passing them to access other resources like SQL Server. I've tried using the `--auth-negotiate-delegate-whitelist` parameter as per this http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/http-authentication, but it doesn't really seem to do anything. I'm still getting `NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON` cannot connect to sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging it seems the best way to handle this is talking with our IT department to deploy software policies to enable kerberos delegation in the registry based on this information here:
http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist

After adding this key to my registry i was able to "hop" to SQL Server without issues. I hope this helps others as this issue was driving me nuts.